# How can I install SSL in cPanel?

Tags: ssl, installation

I have a problem with my cPanel. I have SSL certificate, but I have done every thing to active SSL certificate but my server does not have (Install and Manage SSL for your site (HTTPS)) this option to active SSL. now, how can I activate my SSL certificate without it? I have attached a screenshot [image: MY Cpanel Screenshot]

Comment: Have you uploaded the certificate?

Comment: Here is complete tutorial : https://snippetnuggets.com/howtos/webTipsAndTricks/miscellaneous/install-free-ssl-with-godaddy-hostinger-hostgator-zerossl-cpanel-padlock.html

Answer (score 0):

Most probably if your server do not have option to **Install and Manage SSL for your site(HTTPS)** that simply means you can not install SSL from your hosting provider. This might be due to you are using free hosting, which do not allow to have this option. In order to use SSL you need to upgrade your hosting account to paid one.

But above all, even if you are on free hosting you can install SSL for free by using [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com). You just need to update your current nameservers to cloudflare nameservers and enable SSL option. That's it. Here is a link to [Cloudflare SSL](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/).

Hope this helps.

Thanks!

Comment: One more thing, how can i know my Cpanel its free or paid?

Comment: That's simple if you have paid any amount that mean it's a paid one or else it's free.